# How to Fetch Most Recent Entity in One-to-Many Relationship with Pagination in JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I'm working with a JPA entity that has a one-to-many relationship. My goal is to efficiently fetch the most recent related entity. However, I'm encountering difficulties with pagination when using the CriteriaBuilder combined with fetch/join API.

Here's the relevant part of my entity setup:

```
@Table(name = "EXPECTED_VERSION_FE")
public class ExpectedVersionFE extends ExpectedVersion {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "expectedVersionFE", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    private Set<ActualVersionFE> actualVersionFEs = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Optional<ActualVersionFE> getLatestActualVersionFE() {
        return this.actualVersionFEs.stream().max(
                Comparator.comparing(ActualVersionFE::getCreatedAt)
        );
    }
}
```

In the above code, I'm trying to get the latest ActualVersionFE associated with ExpectedVersionFE. However, I'm not able to implement pagination in this scenario.

I'm considering the use of @BatchSize and a custom query to achieve this, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Is there a way to efficiently fetch the latest relation in a paginated manner using JPA and Hibernate?